# Program only loops once yet it's supposed to loop T times

Tags: java, list, loops

I'll paste all the code here. I've been working on this for a while. Got it to finally work but it only goes through the first loop, where input most of the data, once. If it's been asked before just guide me on what exactly to search for.

```
public class Sol {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<List<List<Integer>>> testCases = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(2);

        int T, N, K, a;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number of Test Cases: ");
        T = input.nextInt();

        for(int count=0; count<T; count++){
            for(int c=0; c<2; c++){
                list.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }
            testCases.add(list);
        }

        for(int count=0; count<T; count++){
            System.out.println("Enter Number of Students and Cancellation Threshold: ");
            N = input.nextInt();
            K = input.nextInt();

            testCases.get(count).get(0).add(N);
            testCases.get(count).get(1).add(K);

            System.out.print("Enter Arrival Times: ");
            int early = 0;
            for(int c=0; c<N; c++){
                List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(N);
                for (int c1=0; c1<N; c1++){
                    a = input.nextInt();
                    list1.add(a);
                    if(a<=0){
                        early++;
                    }
                }
                list.add(list1);
                System.out.println("Is Class Cancelled?");
                if(early>=K){
                    System.out.print("No");
                }
                else
                    System.out.print("Yes");
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: be more specific, what does it do, what do you expect it to do, for which input, ... ? You may want to start improving your code. int T ... what is that supposed to mean? give your variables meaningful names, that are according to naming conventions. For most developers, T will be a generic type

Comment: could you include some sample input and what actually happens where?

Comment: It's supposed to retrieve a number of testcases. within each test case i'll input a certain number of students and a threshold. the threshold holds a value for how many students should be present in class. after i input values equal to the number of students, if below 0, they are early, if above 0 they are late. i get the number of how many are early and if so it prints "No" to say classes aren't cancelled, otherwise yes. It only loops through the 1st testcase and stops

Comment: sample output:  Enter Number of Test Cases: 
3
Enter Number of Students and Cancellation Threshold: 
4 2
Enter Arrival Times: 1 0 -1 3
Is Class Cancelled?
No. It should loop 2 more times

Comment: T is for testcases, N number of students, K the threshold and a the arrival times

Comment: it does prompt quite often for values, but definitly doesn´t stop after the first iteration.

Comment: after it runs the first loop, the one that starts with "Enter Number of Students and Cancellation Threshold:" and ends with either "Yes" or "No", it should output the line "Enter Number of Students and Cancellation Threshold: ". it doesn't do that

Comment: since the printing of `Yes` and `No` are encapsulated in a loop aswell it is going to just prompt `N` times for values, aswell as it will loop another `N` times and print `is Class Cancelled`. You basicly have to do `N*N` inputs before you are seeing the `Enter Number of Students and Cancellation Threshold:` beeing printed again. If you just continue inputing number you´ll see that it does what it does, quite much looping.

Comment: Just tried it. it works. +1 Kevin Esche. Maybe u meant to write your "enter arrival" inside the For(int c=0; c<N; c++)

Comment: Please put the sample input and output _in the question_ not in comments. Edit the question.

Comment: thank you. i added a break; after the "Yes" and "No" part and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an inner loop, which requests input, and which outputs "Yes" or "No":

```
        for(int c=0; c<N; c++){
            List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(N);
            for (int c1=0; c1<N; c1++){
                a = input.nextInt();
                // Requires input!
                // ...
            }
            // ...
            System.out.println("Is Class Cancelled?");
            if(early>=K){
                System.out.print("No");
            }
            else
                System.out.print("Yes");
        }
```

So, once it has printed "No", it will go to the next iteration of the loop and read more input.

The program isn't failing to loop again - it is stuck in the inner loop, waiting for more input.